# ggplot2 theme axis.line. axes do not connect at origin

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, axis

When trying to add custom axes using `axis.line` within `theme()` in `ggplot2`, the axes do not "perfectly" connect at origin. I use `size=3` to see this effect better. Is there a way to fix this?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
geom_point()+
theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size=3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/2.1.0/topics/element_line) of the `element_line` function lists some parameters.  Of particular interest is the parameter `lineend=`.  Default value is `"butt"`.  If you set this to `"square"` it fixes the issue:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
    geom_point()+
    theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black", size=3, lineend = 'square'))
```

[image]